# raster2pgsql error required password

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

i'm trying to import raster to postgis using this command ;

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 4326 -t 100x100 -M "C:\DATA TRIAL APOLLO\mosaik129_130.ecw" -F public.mosaik129_130 | psql -d apollo_db
```

but then error message :

```
ERROR: unable to read raster file: C:\DATA TRIAL APOLLO\mosaik129_130.ecw
```

and it's requiring a password, even on my windows account, i'm not setting any password.

does anyone have solutions?

Comment: Try to use -w switch(no password), may be together with -U (user).

Comment: still doesn't work. i input :

`raster2pgsql -I -C -s 4326 -t 100x100 -M "C:\DATA TRIAL APOLLO\mosaik129_130.ecw" -F public.mosaik129_130 | psql -d apollo_db -w switch`. and it goes :

`ERROR: unable to read raster file: C:\DATA TRIAL APOLLO\mosaik129_130.ecw
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Comment: It's requiring you to supply a password for the database, not windows. If you have ever used anything else to connect to the database then you probably know what information to supply. Regarding "unable to read raster file" though, are you sure that your gdal supports .ecw files ?

Comment: i also try using other raster format (.tif). but the result is still the same `ERROR: unable to read raster file`. i also already input the postgresql database password, it's still error like this :

`psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "amal"` 
i already check `pgpass.conf`, input the password stated there, and still goes failed. and for windows account, i'm not setting any password.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: Try forward slashes

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem. 
But The main problem is ECW format that you need to install GDAL Plugin for it.
Please have a look [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html)